# useEffect cleanup function not called react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

I have been trying to use a cleanup function to cancel the API call I a user presses the back button before the request is resolved.
However I still receive the same error "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.".
I am using fetch function, I added the abortController but still I receive the same warning.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer, useContext } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import AllThumbnails from "../components/AllThumbnails";
import reducer from "../functions/reducer";
import { lightColors, darkColors } from "../constants/Colors";
import { ThemeContext } from "../context/context";
import ScreenContainer from "../components/UI/ScreenContainer";

export default function AllCatScreen(props) {
    const { navigation, route } = props;
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { catPage: 1 });
    const [theme] = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const { taxonomy } = route.params;

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortCtrl = new AbortController();
        const opts = { signal: abortCtrl.signal };
        let isActive = true;

        fetch(`${siteURL}/wp-json/wp/v2/${taxonomy.endPoint}`, opts)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((res) => {
                if (isActive) {
                    setCategories([...categories, ...res]);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        return function cleanup() {
            isActive = false;
            console.log(isActive);
            abortCtrl.abort();
        };
    }, []);

    if (categories.length == 0) {
        return (
            <ScreenContainer notYet={true}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={theme.colors.text} />
            </ScreenContainer>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <ScreenContainer notYet={false}>
                <AllThumbnails
                    data={categories}
                    navigation={navigation}
                    catThumb={true}
                    action={[state, dispatch]}
                    fetchData={fetchData}
                />
            </ScreenContainer>
        );
    }
}
```

I have read that react native should support the AbortController. I am using Expo SDK 38 but even in the clean up function logging the console doesn't work. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Something really weird going on here - you shouldn't need the `AbortController` at all to suppress the warning. Minimal example (with warning suppressed by cleanup function): https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-torvalds-xzqer?file=/src/App.js Can you post your full component code?

Comment: Ok, I updated the code in the post.

Comment: Still not seeing anything that would cause that warning. Are you certain it's coming from this component? What's the stack trace?

Comment: The warning is triggered when I go to the screen then after going to the screen I press the back button before the API request completes.

Comment: This occurs only based on the above behavior, not as a general case.

Comment: Does the warning end with `in AllCatScreen (at AllCatScreen.js:25)` (or whatever the file name is)?

Comment: Have you tried using an arrow function instead for your cleanup like return () => { isActive = false; ... } ?

Comment: I am sorry this was a fault of mine. I used the code on the wrong screen. When I added it to the right one, everything worked well.